# Honor 4C (Marshmallow) Doesn't Connect to PC In Fastboot and Rescue Mode

Tags: adb, fastboot, huawei, bootloader-lock

I've an honor 4c which I recently updated to Marshmallow. I'm trying to unlock bootloader for it and I've got an unlock code. But the problem is, when I enter in Fastboot and Rescue mode (I heard only about fastboot mode only but it opens Fastboot and rescue mode), the device isn't connected to pc. It does open the hisuite on PC when I connect usb cable but it doesn't connect the device. When I enter command, 'adb devices' in Fastboot cmd, it doesn't give any result. I've used ADB drivers, Universal ADB drivers and so on, they work and connect the phone to pc when the phone is switched on but when it goes to fastboot and rescue mode, the phone doesn't connect to hisuite. In device manager it remains present but it doesn't connect to hisuite in fastboot mode. What's the problem and what I'm supposed to do in order to overcome it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need fastboot installed in order to use fastboot commands.

Download **[Minimal ADB and Fastboot](https://androidmtk.com/download-minimal-adb-and-fastboot-tool)** which is a command-line tool. HiSuite doesn't connect to devices via fastboot.

Install it and run it, then type `fastboot devices` to check if the device is recognised.

To proceed with the unlock process, type `fastboot oem unlock`, this should prompt for a password then enter the password that was given to you. 
Or simply type `fastboot oem unlock xxxxxxxxxxx`. Replace the code received from Huawei.

Comment: I'm doing exactly the same but the devices isn't getting connected.

Comment: Double-check  your  drivers. You probably  don't have fastboot drivers installed.

Comment: I'm using fastboot drivers too

Comment: Try drivers from here: https://redirect.viglink.com/?format=go&jsonp=vglnk_148515661166814&key=f0a7f91912ae2b52e0700f73990eb321&libId=iy9rux3201000n4o000MAi7abfpz6d8xp&loc=https%3A%2F%2Fforum.xda-developers.com%2Fhonor-4c%2Fdevelopment%2Fhonor-4c-root-twrplollipop-recovery-t3208922&v=1&out=http%3A%2F%2Fadbdriver.com%2Fdownloads%2F&title=%5BROOT%5D%5BLOLLIPOP%5D%5BHONOR%204C%5D%20Root%2CRecovery%20%26am%E2%80%A6%20%7C%20Honor%204C&txt=LINK%20FOR%20ADB%20DRIVER%20INSTALLER

Comment: From ADB, reboot in fastboot mode with `adb reboot bootloader`

Comment: yes i'm using all of them, the only problem is that device is not connecting in fastboot mode.

Comment: While in fastboot, what is the  output of  fastboot devices?

Comment: ok it's done, i was using adb devices command instead of fastboot devices. now it's unlocked, thanks alot.